# Drivers are not detected on my Dell Inspiron 5420 (14R 3rd generation)

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, 10.10

I'm using Dell inspiron 5420 (14R 3rd generation), and tried to install Ubuntu 10.10, 11.10, 12.04, 12.04.1 but each and every time, it doesn't support any of my driver such as network card, wireless driver, video driver and as well as audio and touch-pad driver. audio, video and touch-pad works with their basic functionality but don't work with their full functionality.

I'm a new user of Ubuntu, and willing to use it permanently. In this condition I tried some solutions from the web but didn't get out from this problem.

For this I'm knocking to you, if you give me the proper solution for getting out of this problem, I'll be very grateful to you all.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Askubuntu :) Next, did you try installing the additional hardware drivers required? If not, try [How do I install extra drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers). Lastly, instead of asking people to mail you the solution, please do check your notifications on any StackExchange sites, or change the settings so that an e-mail is sent to you once every three hours if there's a new notification for you.

Comment: We can't mail the directions to you, you did not leave your mailing address... all I see is an email address...

Answer (score 1):

This is my [**compilation**](http://andri.andriani.web.id/wired-network-and-wireless-network-dell-inspiron/) for networking in Dell Inspiron 5420 using 12.04. To find the link please visit my blog.

To activate wire network:

1. Install compat wireless with this version [compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p](http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p.tar.bz2)

   ```
   ./scripts/driver-select alx
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
2. Reboot and plug in your wire network.
3. After you wired network is up now its time fire up the wireless. Download this [file](http://wielki.tk/vostro/debs/wlan_amd64.deb).

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i wlan_amd64.deb
   ```

   First time it will fail then you have to do

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```

   then it will get all file need to install `wlan_amd64.deb`
4. Reboot your laptop.

All done.

Comment: Please consider using official pre-built compat-wireless packages instead of compiling from source and install packages from unofficial sources. See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/233587/88802) in another question.