# How to install network drivers in Dell Inspiron 5420?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom, atheros

I am using Dell Inspiron 5420 (14R 3rd gen). Wireless and wired works fine in Windows 7, but I do not get any in Ubuntu 12.04. `lspci` gives the following data:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros
```

I tried using this link answer: [Drivers are not detected on my Dell Inspiron 5420 (14R 3rd generation)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193333/drivers-are-not-detected-on-my-dell-inspiron-5420-14r-3rd-generation)
but I get the following error :

```
bash: ./scripts/driver-select: Permission denied
```

Comment: Please try [My WiFi adapter is not working at all. Where to start troubleshooting?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-where-to-start-troubleshooting)

Answer (score 1):

I have a Dell Inspiron 5420 Laptop. I was struggling to install Wired Network drivers. The article above helped me in installing them. But after installing the wired network successfully, I tried to install Wireless Network drivers. I found out that I have "Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)" after typing `lspci` on the terminal.

I also tried the wireless setup guide given above, but was unable to install it, because it was saying that I have the i386 package installed and I cannot use amd64. After trying many different things, I tried to update my Ubuntu 12.04 to studio i386.

After all the updates were successfully installed. The system automatically asked me to install Broadcom Wireless, by clicking "yes" all my troubles were gone and now it is working smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Download the driver from [here](http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p.tar.bz2)

and copy that driver to desktop.

Open terminal (Alt+ Ctrl + T) and paste the following commands one by one.

```
cd ~/Desktop
tar -xvf compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p.tar.bz2
cd compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p
scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
sudo modeprobe alx
```

Now you are able to connect the Internet. Happy Ubuntu..!!!

Comment: -1 for building from source. `compat-wireless` updates are available using packages. Try `apt-cache search linux-backports-modules-cw`.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing more recent wireless drivers (kernel modules) using backported compat-wireless modules. Ubuntu has packages available for this.

For example, try installing the package `linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic` and just to be sure, install the firmware modules as well. Example command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic linux-firmware linux-firmware-nonfree
```

This metapackage will install the appropriate backported kernel modules from the Linux 3.6 source for your current Precise kernel (3.2). For the `linux-firmware-nonfree` you'll need to have the multiverse repository enabled (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository) on how to do that).

Then reboot and see if your wireless adapter is recognized properly.