# How to Install network drivers on Dell Iinspiron 5420 with Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, 10.04

I followed this to install network driver
[How to install network drivers in Dell Inspiron 5420?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233575/how-to-install-network-drivers-in-dell-inspiron-5420) but it show me this error

```
$sudo make
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-38-generic/build M=/home/cyberboy/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-38-generic'
scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/cyberboy/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** No rule to make target `/home/cyberboy/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [/home/cyberboy/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx] Error 2
make[2]: *** [/home/cyberboy/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros] Error 2
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/cyberboy/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-38-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I have Dell Inspiron 5420 Ubuntu 10.04 64bit.

Comment: what is your kernel ? use `uname -a` to see. That answer is for 12.04. So possibly 10.04 isn't compatible

Comment: Linux cyberboy-laptop 2.6.32-38-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:12:07 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: try following http://askubuntu.com/a/233587/35775

Comment: E: Couldn't find package linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic
Also i added the multiverse repository.

Answer (score 0):

You know, network connections are something the linux community has actively moved to give more support. You may want to go ahead and upgrade if possible, and any network issue might solve themselves.

I have on several experiences had laptops that would not connect to wifi on 9.10, but once upgraded to 10.04 or to 10.10 the wireless worked.

Doesn't help your exact issue, but it could make your question unnecessary.